# XMLHttpRequest how to parse response to string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, text, xmlhttprequest, byte

I am trying to parse the response I get from a uri into strings, and display it on a webpage. The response is in byte stream. Below is what I have at the moment. It doesn't work. The debugger says "ReferenceError: result is not defined". How can I parse the bytes into string? Many thanks for your help in advance!

```
var uri = "some uri to get text in byte stream"
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();     
    xhr.open("GET", uri,true);
    xhr.onload= function(){
        var result = xhr.responseText;//it doesn't display the text     
    }   
    xhr.send(null);

document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = result;//display result on a page
```

Comment: put the last line just after the `var result =` line ... it's all about scope, and in a way asynchronous functions

Comment: ^ there's that, and the only valid datatype in `responseText` is a string. If it really is binary data, you should be using `xhr.response`. Maybe reading a bit on [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data) helps ?

Comment: Thanks guys! @JaromandaX 's solution works for me in this case